# Dell Inspiron i660s-5386BK won’t recognize hard disk which works OK

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, bios, dell-inspiron

After running Windows Update, my computer wouldn't restart. Stated no hard drive. Pressed F12 at startup to run diagnostics - everything passed but said there was no hard drive!

I purchased a USB Hard Disk Drive Enclosure and looked at the disk from another computer - the disk is fine!  It even shows the last update in a log file!

I've tried another hard drive in the slot, same problem. So there is something changed or wrong in the boot area of the computer - it won't run from a CD or DVD or external either. Dell Inspiron i660s with Windows 8.

Originally asked at Microsoft Community [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-system/after-windows-update-computer-reboot-to-a-black/bef9cb89-7237-44b4-a6a4-a562cb77462c).

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue, the HDD connector may be damaged. Try going into the BIOS and reset everything to default.

Comment: Agree enter the bios and load default settings, then see if detects the hard drive.

Comment: Thank you, have tried loading default settings; how can I tell if the HDD connector is damaged?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hardware issue since the drive is completely unavailable and symptoms are the same even with a different drive. However it's not limited to hardware and may be something with your BIOS settings. Try the following:

~ Test/Change the SATA cable: SATA cables for 3.5" Desktop HDD's are pretty common to come by, from the 'other' computer you mention? Simply take the side panel off of your desktop, locate **[this](https://www.google.com/search?q=sata%20cable&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ElhvVeC5HsODsAXc_4DAAg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg#imgrc=yffX9la2DJNFJM%253A%3BGF5YUXdRnSyrcM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fecx.images-amazon.com%252Fimages%252FI%252F41gujVdrWtL._SY300_.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.amazon.com%252FStarTech-Right-Angle-Serial-SATA18RA1%252Fdp%252FB0001Y8UI4%3B300%3B300)** cable and try testing the hard drive using a different one, if you have an extra on hand. It may also be an issue with the power, in which case the process is the same except for **[this](https://www.google.com/search?q=sata%20power%20cable&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=aVhvVe_EN8fYsAWjhYGoAg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg#imgrc=4szsY2cUDANkuM%253A%3BciiLRE4NhRUzdM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fcdn.shopclues.net%252Fimages%252Fdetailed%252F462%252F25xPiecesSata4c3176ed30bd1_1367996833.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.shopclues.com%252Fsata-power-cable.html%3B1257%3B704)** cable.

~ UEFI/Legacy: First try reverting to default settings in your BIOS, like others have previously suggested. You can also try changing BIOS settings from UEFI to Legacy or vice-versa. Here's the gist if you're completely unfamiliar: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyabVjIZik0). Consider also that, depending on the BIOS, you may need to make other changes to the HDD/Boot order. These other potential changes may not be available until you "Save Changes" and restart **back** into BIOS.

The BIOS issue mentioned may also be the culprit for not being able to boot from CD/External meduim.

Comment: I believe I tried using other cables before, but will attempt it in the morning.  Nothing had been moved on or in the computer when it booted itself after the update.  Then I will try the different BIOS settings.

The hard drive is readable and I am not willing to compromise the information on it, nor the programs installed.
Thanks, Pam